# Para que serve o arquivo .gitattributes?

Tags: git

- Quando devo usar o arquivo de `.gitattributes` ?
- O que posso fazer com ele ?
- Quando não usar este arquivo ?
- É uma boa prática ter sempre um arquivo `.gitattributes` em meus repositórios ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O arquivo .gitattributes serve de controle para uma série de ações do GIT. Desconheço contra-indicações ao seu uso, entretanto, como sempre, é importante fazer o seu uso de forma consciente, evitando resultados não esperados. [Há uma série de templates bem documentados](https://github.com/alexkaratarakis/gitattributes) e muitas IDEs também criam o mesmo ao inicializar um novo repositório.

O uso mais comum do .gitattributes talvez seja para o controle de *line endings*. Tomando o default do Visual Studio como exemplo:

```
* text=auto
*.sh text eol=lf
```

`* text=auto` fará com que o GIT use o seu padrão para arquivos texto e converterá arquivos *CRLF* para *LF* no checkin, por exemplo. Dessa maneira o repositório ficará com um único padrão, mesmo que diferentes sistemas operacionais sejam usados.

`*.sh text eol=lf` fará com que os arquivos `.sh` sejam excluídos do comportamento acima, mantendo-se como `LF`. Isso é especialmente útil quando se tem arquivos `.sh` em um computador Windows usados em containers Linux.

Analogamente, podemos ter o mesmo para arquivos tipicamente de Windows, como `.bat`, `.cmd` e `.ps1`.

Um uso interessante é para o `export-ignore`, permitindo "excluir" diretórios e arquivos ao exportar um repositório (como quando usuários fazem o download do repositório como .zip diretamente do GitHub). Neste caso, poderiam ser excluídos arquivos específicos do GIT (como o .gitignore e o próprio .gitattributes), bem como diretórios de testes e outros artefatos que não devem ser relevantes às pessoas que querem somente executar algo do seu repositório.

Answer (score 4):

O .gitattributes é um arquivo de texto simples que fornece atributos específicos para arquivos e diretórios dentro do seu repositório. Com ele você pode configurar várias coisas, como por exemplo: resolver problemas visuais do diff na sua solicitação de merge, selecionar uma ação automática quando houver conflitos, converter finais de linhas em arquivos baseados em texto e etc…

Pode ler mais sobre este assunto [aqui](https://medium.com/joaorobertopb/otimize-seu-reposit%C3%B3rio-git-utilizando-o-arquivo-gitattributes-82a23517dcd0)